# Перенаправление запросов на поддомен из папки основного домена (Apache, htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

Не могу разобраться, может кто подскажет?)

Требуется сделать перенаправление запросов с папки site.ru/catalog/ на поддомен catalog.site.ru

Т.е. при открытии в браузере site.ru/catalog/ у пользователя открывалась страница с catalog.site.ru, но в адресной строке все оставалось как прежде (site.ru/catalog/ и так далее для чпу)

Нужно написать как я понял условие в .htaccess и положить его в корень в site.ru/catalog/

catalog.site.ru в свою очередь чтобы переадресовывал на site.ru/catalog/, не доступен был из браузера